# how to bind a service related message to the NgxuiLoader?

Tags: angular, angular8

// app.component.html

```
    <ngx-ui-loader fgsColor="white" fgsSize="large" fgsType="square-jelly-box" text="Loading!"></ngx- 
    ui-loader>
```

// the above code will display loader text **Loading!** which is binded to text.
Expectation : for ex. if i am calling a service for getCustomers() i want to display some message say "Loading Customers!" with the loader.

Answer (score 1):

just add a variable that holds the string you want and pass it to text

//app.component.html

```
<ngx-ui-loader fgsColor="white" fgsSize="large" fgsType="square-jelly-box" [text]="loading"></ngx- 
ui-loader>
```

//app.component.ts

```
loading:string;
 setLoading(serviceCalled){
// based on service set loading text...
}
```

also call the setter in service and pass required parameter to the loading string